# redirect sub domain in htaccess file

Tags: 7

I have tried a number of ways to try to redirect a sub url in my htaccess file with very little progress, and I know I am doing it correctly but for some reason it just is not working, and as far as I can tell there is no module that can do this. I am simply trying to direct a sub domain to the main domain.

This is the code I am using.

```
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^red.sitename.com$ http://sitename.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Now I have red somewhere that you have to do it this a certain way when clean urls is enabled and this is suppose to be the correct way but it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The piece you are missing is [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

This should redirect just the subdomain

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^red\.sitename\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note also that the separator needs to be escaped as `\.` to prevent it from being used as a single character match in the pattern.  The `[NC]` also tells Apache to ignore case during the match.